# Probability of filled cell given marginal sums

Tags: probability, matrix

Let $\mathcal{M}(R,C)$ be the set of all $r \times c$ binary matrices $M$ with row sums $R$ and column sums $C$. In what fraction of matrices in $\mathcal{M}$ is $M_{11} = 1$?

One possibility is to sample matrices from $\mathcal{M}$, computing $mean(M_{11})$ over the sample. I've used this approach in the simple case where $R = 1,2,1$ and $C = 1,2,1$. Because $\mathcal{M}$ contains only 5 matrices in this case, I can confirm that with sufficient sampling this approach gives 0.2, which is correct. But, this approach would take impractically long to converge on stable fractions if $M$ (and therefore $\mathcal{M}$) is large.

I've also tried generating one $M$, then fitting a logistic regression modeling $M_{ij}$ as a function of the row and column sums, then using the predicted probability of $M_{11} = 1$. This is fast, and in many cases the fractions are close to correct, but not always.

Comment: What probability distribution are you assuming??

Comment: I'm not assuming a probability distribution. I'd like to know the probability that $M_{ij} = 1$ over all $M$ with the prescribed row and column sums.

Comment: If you're not assuming a probability distribution then you don't even have a basis to ask a question about a probability!  If you could describe the intended application then perhaps readers could suggest suitable distributions (or equivalent assumptions) to make this question answerable.

Comment: I've edited the question to frame it in terms of the fraction of times $M_{ij} = 1$ in the space of all matrices $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: That is now perfectly clear, thank you.  Shall we presume you are referring to some predetermined (but arbitrary) $ij$ rather than asking for the fraction where *some* (or perhaps *all?*) $M_{ij}=1$?

Comment: I'd like to determine the fraction of matrices in $\mathcal{M}$ for which $M_{ij} = 1$, for all $ij$. So, the solution could take the form of a matrix $M'$ with the same dimensions, row sums, and column sums as $M$, but where the cell contents have the range [0,1].

Comment: That is confusing, because (1) you refer to *binary* matrices which, presumably, contain only zeros and ones yet (2) by asking that $M_{ij}=1$ for all $ij$ you specify exactly one matrix (which might or might not have the requisite marginal totals), thereby trivializing the problem. Your example seems instead to fix an arbitrary $ij$ and reports on the results for *each* such $ij.$ Note that because you can arbitrarily permute the rows and the columns without changing the nature of the problem, it would suffice to ask for a general answer for the two cases $ij=11$ and $ij=12.$

Comment: I've edited the question again, to only ask about $M_{11}$, which will generalize to any other cell. Because $M$ is not necessarily square, I think the answer for $ij = 11$ should generalize to $ij = 12$.

Comment: You're right of course: all cells are equivalent when rows and columns are independently permuted, which is what I was thinking of.   Thanks for pointing that out!